# Polyhedron not circumscribed about a sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a polyhedron whose faces are colored black and white so that there are more black faces and no two black faces are adjacent. Show that $P$ is not circumscribed about a sphere.

My teacher has conjectured this. I haven't been able to produce a counterexample, neither a solution. Is this claim true? If not a counterexample would be nice. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: One way to get examples of polyhedra with more black faces than white, no two adjacent, is to start with a polyhedron with more vertices than faces, then truncate it, coloring the new faces black and the old faces white. So far the examples like this that I have tried can't be circumscribed about a sphere.

Comment: The polar dual of a circumscribable polyhedron is inscribable. Perhaps the work on conditions for inscribable polyhedra can help: Michael Dillencourt and Warren Smith. "Graph-theoretical conditions for inscribability and Delaunay realizability." *Discrete Mathematics* 161.1 (1996): 63-77.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is exercise 21.3, of [Mathematical Omnibus: Thirty Lectures on Classic Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821843168), by D.B. Fuks and Serge Tabachnikov. The solution is given on page 448:

> Assume that $P$ is circumscribed. Consider a face $A_1$, $A_2$,...
>   $A_n$ and let $O$ be its tangency point with the sphere. Clearly, the
>   sum of angles $A_i O A_{i+1}$ is $2\pi$. We shall sum up al these
>   angles over all faces, taking the angles in the white faces with
>   positive signs and the angles in the black faces with negative signs.
>   Since there are more black faces, this sum, $\Sigma$, is negative.
>
> On the other hand, consider two adjacent faces with a common edge
>   $AB$; see figure; The angles $AOB$ and $AO'B$ are equal. Indeed,
>   revolve the plane $AOB$ about the line $AB$ (as if it were a hinge)
>   until it coincides with the plane $AO'B$. This rotation takes point
>   $O$ to $O'$ and hence the triangles $AOB$ and $AO'B$ are congruent.
>
> There are two kinds of adjacent faces; black-white and white-white;
>   the former's contribution to $\Sigma$ cancels, and the latter
>   contribute a positive number. Thus $\Sigma\geq 0$, a contradiction.

[image]

Comment: Very impressive. I may just have to buy this book.

Comment: I have a question, how can we ensure $\Sigma<0$? The black faces may contribute angular sum small enough to keep the sum positive. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: @shadow10 --- each face contributes the same amount $2\pi$ in absolute value to $\Sigma$, so $\Sigma=(N_{\rm white}-N_{\rm black})\times 2\pi<0$ if there are more black than white faces.

Comment: Oh thank you @CarloBeenakker I did miss something obvious. My apologies, thank you for clearing it up.