# A conjecture about cross sections of a pyramid

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Show that for $n\ge 5$, a cross-section of a pyramid whose base is a regular $n$-gon cannot be a regular $(n + 1)$-gon.
This is a conjecture I came across while trying to solve [this problem.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172481/polyhedron-not-circumscribed-about-a-sphere)
I was drawing many figures and three dimensional figures and pyramids were the first choice. And I observed this. I have no proof, or even ideas to a proof. But seems true. Any counter example would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not suitable to MO. Sketch of proof: 1. a section which is a $(n+1)$-gon must meet all faces of the pyramid; 2. it is therefore not parallel to he base; 3. By an explicit computation, show that not edges of the section can have the same length.

Comment: Sorry about posting wrongly, but I didn't know where to put it. I suppose you wouldn't tell me about the computation part, anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) has a more general scope regarding math questions, you can try there if you do not solve the question by yourself.

Comment: You might observe that "three edges of the n+1 gon have to fit in two edges of the n gon".

Comment: Could you clarify a bit on your comment? @TheMaskedAvenger I don't get what you mean by "fitting in". And I ask everyone that if it is not suitable for this site, could you have it migrate to Math SE? Because I think it is interesting. Sorry for all inconvenience.

Comment: The pyramid faces provide n edges of the cross section; the remaining edge has to be a chord of the base, and either lie on an edge of the base, or "clip off" a corner of the base.  If both polygons are to be regular, you will have length issues with the sides as you are "trying to fit three edges in the space of two" while at the same time keeping the edges in the cross section of the same length.

Comment: I suspect something more general is true, that you can't have an ngonal base,  an (n+1)gonal cross section, and insist on some combination of equiangular or equilateral to apply to the polygons.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Thanks for taking the time to reply, but this is not entirely clear to me. Can this be put off hold? A clear answer would be helpful, comments are not clear to me. Sorry for my ignorance. If not then, can this be migrated to Math SE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I imagine migration will happen.  Ask yourself this: if your conjecture were false, how long would the chord at the base of the polygon have to be to be part of the cross section?